# Corporate user cannot ping computer on network

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, ping, domain

At my company we are on a corporate network connected with domain ***main.mycompany.com***. I also have a domain-less computer running under my desk that I use for development work as well as running a license server for product XYZ. About 15 of us at this location A can ping this server and also check out licenses no problem.

One of our users is at location B and is also connected to the same domain but cannot ping the server (either by name or IP address). She can VPN into her desktop at location A and also ping any computer anywhere as long as its on the domain. Why cant she see the domain-less server but we at location A can see it without problems?

They are all running Windows 7 Enterprise. I compared ipconfig from her computer and mine. Primary Dns Suffix is the same (main.mycompany.com) as well as all other settings. The only thing I see that is different is that she has Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection>Connection-specific DNS Suffix = ***pxx.legacycompany.com*** and I have Local Area Connection>Connection-specific DNS Suffix = ***main.mycompany.com***. Is this the issue? What else can I check or have her test to have her ping the server?

Comment: OK maybe I should have cleared it up a little bit. She isn't trying to VPN or RDP into the server. All she is trying to do is ping it so that she can check out a license. She has tried to ping several domain-less servers and all time out. let me see what the OS firewall says about ICMP.

Comment: Check the server OS firewalls and perhaps start with one, disable it, have her try and see if that makes any difference. I assume location B is a different subnet than location A even if on the same domain whether local or domain joined machine that you use. I assume it's not just her in location B that has this issue and that it's every one or every machine from that subnet you try to ping that doesn't respond. Process of elimination to start with I would think would be best.

Comment: So the server is at 10.57.x.x with subnet mask 255.255.255.0. At my location which is A the address is 10.57.x.x same subnet mask. The user who cannot ping the server is at location B with 10.7.x.x same subnet.

Comment: What communication on the network is available between the sites if any? Did the server FW disabling test make any difference? Are you going by what you are being told or what you can see yourself at location B? Is there a router in the middle you could check its logs to see if it's blocking something? Are you available at Location A and B or remotely to B and at A or what's the situation there? Are you having trouble getting a site VPN up with a ping request by chance or something along those lines? Can U explain data network device setup between subnets to get them to talk (e.g. Cisco ASA)?

Comment: I'm not an admin so I can't get most of that info. I'm physically only at location A and can have her test from location B. I've had her ping the IP address and name of the server from location B.

Comment: Get a remote session going so you can drive the remote computer and ensure commands, etc. are being typed in properly and so on with Team Viewer or something. Also you should consider reaching out to the network admin to show you how to get logs from the routers or they confirm it's not being blocked at those levels.

Comment: Opened ports on the server as instructed by tech support from the third party company. She can connect now via IP. Doesn't work via name but that's fine. As long as she can connect.